# Can't locate the correct beautifulsoup class and id combo

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have the following code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = 'https://www.youtube.com/gaming/games'

response = requests.get(URL).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')

elem = soup.find_all('a', class_ = 'yt-simple-endpoint focus-on-expand style-scope ytd-game-details-renderer')

print(elem)
```

I am trying to isolate all the individual games on https://www.youtube.com/gaming/games.

I would like to just get the game name and how many people are watching. My issue is that I just can't find the right `" ", class\_ = '' "` combo.

I've tried the following:
`soup.find_all`:

```
('a', class\_ = 'yt-simple-endpoint focus-on-expand style-scope ytd-game-details-renderer')
('game', class\_ = 'style-scope ytd-game-card-renderer')
(class\_ = 'style-scope ytd-grid-renderer')
(id = 'items')
```

And many different variations.

If I just use `find_all('div')` I get random data. I really think (`id = 'items'`) is my solution, but aside from `'div'` I get the same response every time, a pair of brackets `\[\]`. I've also tried searching the individual div class objects I get in the results, but so far I'm getting the same `[]` results or random data that I don't need.

If I use find instead of `find_all (elem = soup.find(id='items'))` I get `"None"` as a response.

I'm looking at the subscriber count, with an id of `'live-viewers-count'`, and it still prints `[]`.

What I'm looking at:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**
Here's how to traverse the game data JSON elements.

First, narrow down to `game_data`, which is a list of JSON elements.

```
game_data = (
    json.loads(main[20:-1])
    ['contents']
    ['twoColumnBrowseResultsRenderer']
    ['tabs'][0]
    ['tabRenderer']
    ['content']
    ['sectionListRenderer']
    ['contents'][0]
    ['itemSectionRenderer']
    ['contents'][0]
    ['shelfRenderer']
    ['content']
    ['gridRenderer']
    ['items']
)
```

Now iterate over the list. For each element, there's a section of the data packet we'll call `details`, which contains game name and views.

Then use the paths I showed in my original answer to capture name and view count for each game.

```
for game in game_data:
    details = (
        game
        ['gameCardRenderer']
        ['game']
        ['gameDetailsRenderer']
    )
    game_name = details['title']['simpleText']
    
    view_ct = details['liveViewersText']['runs'][0]['text']
    
    print(f"Game: {game_name} / Views: {view_ct}")
```

Output

```
Game: Valorant / Views: 100K
Game: Grand Theft Auto V / Views: 61K
Game: Dota 2 / Views: 57K
Game: Minecraft / Views: 50K
# ...
```

**Original answer**

All of the data you need is stored as JSON in one of the `<script>` tags, it's just a pain to follow down the nested object to the fields you need. You can see it's all there if you just look at `soup.body`.

I had a few spare minutes just now, this should get you started - shows you how to get to the Game and Live Viewers count for the first game listed currently ('Valorant')

```
import json

# buried as JSON in a <script> inside <body>
main = soup.body.find_all('script')[13].contents[0]
```

This is how you get to game name (you can iterate instead of indexing [0] to get all the games):

```
# Game name
print('Game:', json.loads(main[20:-1])
 ['contents']
 ['twoColumnBrowseResultsRenderer']
 ['tabs'][0]
 ['tabRenderer']
 ['content']
 ['sectionListRenderer']
 ['contents'][0]
 ['itemSectionRenderer']
 ['contents'][0]
 ['shelfRenderer']
 ['content']
 ['gridRenderer']
 ['items'][0]
 ['gameCardRenderer']
 ['game']
 ['gameDetailsRenderer']
 ['title']
 ['simpleText']
)
```

Output

```
Game: Valorant
```

And this is Viewer Count:

```
print('Live Viewers:', json.loads(main[20:-1])
 ['contents']
 ['twoColumnBrowseResultsRenderer']
 ['tabs'][0]
 ['tabRenderer']
 ['content']
 ['sectionListRenderer']
 ['contents'][0]
 ['itemSectionRenderer']
 ['contents'][0]
 ['shelfRenderer']
 ['content']
 ['gridRenderer']
 ['items'][0]
 ['gameCardRenderer']
 ['game']
 ['gameDetailsRenderer']
 ['liveViewersText']
 ['runs'][0]
 ['text'])
```

Output

```
Live Viewers: 100K
```

Comment: Good eye! I vote for this!

Comment: I guess I should re-word my comment, I'm trying to follow your suggestion of "you can iterate instead of indexing [0] to get all the games" but I'm not exactly sure which value you manipulate to display all data. I'm getting key errors on all my attempts.

Comment: You need to iterate through `items`.  If I have some time later I can add syntax for a loop.

Comment: @user21090678 here you go!

Comment: @andrew_reece This is fantastic. Thank you so much for this! I was concerned about the keyerror in the code, but this fetches 50-something results so it's a non-issue. I just slapped the good'ol except Exception on it and it's working great. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do this because this page is loaded dynamically with **javascript**.

**BeautifulSoup** doesn't run **javascript**.

See, when right-clicking in the page and selecting `show page source`, there is mostly just *compiled* javascript.

To scrape youtube, I'd either use [**Selenium**](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to run a headless web-browser, or [**Js2Py**](https://github.com/PiotrDabkowski/Js2Py) if you need performance.

... or simply use youtube APIs : https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs ^_^'